# Count the number of executable files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have seen a lot of answers about this subject but I don't want to do this using
`find`. I have written this but something not working:

```
function CountEx()
{
    count=0
    for file in `ls $1`
    do
        echo "file is $file"
        if [ -x $file ]
        then
            count=`expr $count + 1`
        fi
    done
    echo "The number of executable files in this dir is: $count"
}
while getopts x:d:c:h opt
do
    case $opt in
        x)CountEx $OPTARG;;
        d)CountDir $OPTARG;;
        c)Comp $OPTARG;;
        h)help;;
        *)echo "Please Use The -h Option to see help"
        break;;
    esac
done
```

I am using this script like the following:

```
yaser.sh -x './..../...../.....'
```

The shell runs it and then it outputs:
`The number of executable files in this dir is: 0`
when there is many executable files in this directory.

Comment: What is "not working"? It's great that you provided your code, but you should also include your expected and actual output.  And if you want people to be able to reproduce your results, describing the input in more detail would be helpful. Oh, and you're *[parsing LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)*.  Don't do that.

Comment: The script is sloppy enough to break on directories with spaces, filenames with special chars and who knows what else, but it definitely works in a sanitized environment (nothing special in file and directory names). Describe how *something* isn't working for you.

Comment: And per the diversity in the answers below, are you looking for the number of *executables*, as you say in your title, or the number of *subdirectories*, as you imply with your code?

Comment: sorry i put the CountDir function instead of CountEx but it's the same problem, because i want to use <B>ls</B> and pass to it <B>$1</B>
then count the number of executable files or directories

Comment: sorry for the mistake i just corrected the function,

Comment: please be patient with me I'm only just getting started with linux
Thanks to every one :)

Comment: We're patient, to a point.  But we're often terse.  I see from your update that your question is substantially different from the original; now you're asking "What's wrong with my script" rather than "How do I count directories."  I suspect that there is sufficient information in the answers below to fix your script.  Note that for debugging, you can try pasting *just the function* into an interactive shell, and see if you can make it work from there.

Comment: Note also that if you are `[ -x $foo ]` will return true for **directories with the x bit set**.  This does not mean that directories are executable, so your script will find an incorrect number of executables.  Instead, test with `[ -x "$foo" -a -f "$foo" ]` to skip directories.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to count directories, there are so many options.

The `find` way, which you said you don't want:

```
CountDir() {
  if [[ ! -d "$1" ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: $1 is not a directory." >&2
    return 1
  fi
  printf "Total: %d\n" $(find "$1" -depth 1 -type d | wc -l)
}
```

The `for` way, similar to your example:

```sh
CountDir() {
  if [[ ! -d "$1" ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: $1 is not a directory." >&2
    return 1
  fi
  count=0
  for dir in "$1"/*; do
    if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
      ((count++))
    fi
  done
  echo "Total: $count"
}
```

The `set` way, which skips the loop entirely.

```sh
CountDir() {
  if [[ ! -d "$1" ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: $1 is not a directory." >&2
    return 1
  fi
  set -- "$1"/*/
  echo "Total: $#"
}
```

Comment: missing `-type d` for `find`, and in the `for` way, `"$1"/*` should be `"$1"/*/`.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko - ya, typing too fast and not paying attention. Thanks, I've fixed the `find`.  Re the for loop, I left it with an `if` to keep it closer to the OP's original code.  Both will work.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko can you please explean to me what /*/ is used for

Comment: For the meaning of `*`, see `Pathname Expansion` in `man bash`. Trailing `/` makes it match directories only.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of executable (like the title says)

```sh
 count=0 
 for file in yourdir/*; do 
     if [ -x $file ]; then 
         count=$((count+1)); 
     fi; 
 done; 
 echo "total ${count}"
```

To count folders, just change the `-x` test with `-d`

Comment: Ya - lack of clarity in the question always makes things interesting.  :-)